# Why didn't CSS adjacent combinator did not work here?

Tags: css

Can someone help me understand why adjacent combinator (+) below isn't working as the commented part of css.

Adjacent combinator (+) should match second selector `.btn` if it *immediately* follows the first selector i.e. `.btn-group` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors and so I was expecting my first btn's background to change to blue.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">
    Save
  </button>

  <button class="btn">
    Revert
  </button>
</div>

/* .btn-group .btn:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
} */

.btn-group + .btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [adjacent **sibling** combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) only targets the immediately preceding **sibling** element, not **child** element. This can be seen in the following:

```css
.btn-group + .btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">
    Save
  </button>

  <button class="btn">
    Revert
  </button>
</div>

<button class="btn">
  Target
</button>
```

If you want to target the very first child, then you do indeed need to use `.btn-group .btn:first-child`. You can add in the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** to increase specificity if required, with `.btn-group > .btn:first-child`:

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Higher specificity with the child combinator */
.btn-group > .btn:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">
    Save
    <span class="btn">Sub-class</span>
  </button>

  <button class="btn">
    Revert
  </button>
</div>
```

Adding the child combinator avoids any descendants other than children also having the rule applied to them as well, which can be confusing in combination with the pseudo-selector **[`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child)**, as demonstrated in the following example:

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Higher specificity without the child combinator */
.btn-group .btn:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">
    Save
    <span class="btn">Sub-class</span>
  </button>

  <button class="btn">
    Revert
  </button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply, `.btn` is a child of `.btn-group` not an adjacent **sibling**.

From the MDN document you linked to:

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and **both are children of the same parent element**.

Emphasis mine,